# Understanding limits of the form $\frac{b}{0}$ where $b = 0$ fixed.

Tags: limits

I'm reviewing limit properties, and one of them states that if, after direct substitution, a limit takes the form $\frac{b}{0}$ where $b$ is fixed (and I assume non-zero, because $\frac{0}{0}$ limits require more work), then I can conclude that the limit does not exist.

Why is this automatically the case? Why can't I try to, via algebra, reduce the limit argument to a more solvable form?

Comment: I think your title might be a bit misleading.

Comment: For the answer is needed an exact quotation of the property that you are interested in and/or the exact source.

Comment: Let $\lim_{x\to r}f(x)=b\ne0$, let $\lim_{x\to r}g(x)=0$, and suppose $\lim_{x\to r}(f(x)/g(x))=c$ for some number $c$. Use the definition of limit to derive a contradiction, Card.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Is it true in general that the one-sided limits will be $+\infty$ and $-\infty$, depending on the sign of $b$? If so, I think I can write this proof using the definition. Thank you.

Comment: The one-sided limits need not exist. Say $r=0$, $f(x)=17$, $g(x)=x\sin(1/x)$. Then $g$ changes sign in every neighborhood of zero, so $f/g$ oscillates between very large positive and very large negative as $x\to0$.

Comment: Making progress, Card?

Comment: I guess not. Too bad.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm very sorry. Your answer helped, and I think I understand it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: You could post an answer, Card.